# Zend Plugin found in view not in layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, plugins, view-helpers

I've got a plugin that retrieves a list of buttons.
When i call this plugin from the view (echo $this->GetAdminButtons()) it works fine.
But I need to call this plugin from the layout.phtml and when i do, the application just stops (white screen, no output)

When i try to get the exception message i get this error:

```
Plugin by name 'GetAdminButtons' was not found in the registry;
used paths: 
    Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_: Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/ 
    Zend_View_Helper_:            Zend/View/Helper/:./views/helpers/
```

In the application.ini

```
resources.view.helperPath.Admin_View_Helper = "Admin/View/Helper"
```

Which confuses me because it works fine in the view .phtml files

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where is the helper located? `views/helpers/GetAdminButtons.php`?

Comment: Its located in the library/Admin/View/Helper/GetAdminButtons.php And this directory is set as a helper path in the application.ini.

Comment: That path is not included in the path list in the error. Could you edit your question to include the relevant part of your application.ini where you set the helper paths?

Comment: Do you by any chance have some lines in your config that start `resources.layout`? If so, does it work if you move them above the view lines?

Comment: The layout lines were already above the view lines. I've also tried to place the file in every known views/helpers folder still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing the discussion from the comments. Try moving the `resources.layout` lines in your config so they are after the `resources.view` ones (my suggestion in the comment had things the wrong way round).

I think your issue is that the layout is being initialized before the view is, which is why the view paths don't exist in the layout.

Comment: I did switch the lines both ways to see if it made any difference but it didn't.

Comment: Do you have any _init methods in your bootstrap class?

Comment: Yes i got a few, also
    protected function _initViewHelpers()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $view = $this->getResource('layout')->getView();
    }

Comment: Ok, any called `_initLayout()` or `_initView()`?

Comment: This is the same problem, just in a different place. Try changing the bootstrap line in that `_initViewHelpers()` to `$this->bootstrap(array('view', 'layout'));` That forces it to bootstrap the view first.

Comment: That did the trick! ($this->bootstrap(array('view', 'layout'));) the plugin is being called! You Rock! thanks a lot!